# The sum of all parameter values for which the graphs of the functions have exactly one common point is?

Tags: quadratics, plane-curves, parametrization, planar-graphs, discriminant

The sum of all parameter $a\in\mathbb{R}$ values for which the graphs of the functions $y=(a+2)x^2-ax-3$ and $y=ax-4$ have exactly one common point is?
The answer in textbook is -1.

This is what I tried:

I need a common point so I equate the two functions.
$$(a+2)x^2-ax-3=ax-4 \to (a+2)x^2-2ax+1=0$$
I need only one common point, therefore only one solution, so the discriminant is zero.
$$D=0 \to 4a^2-4(a+2)=0 \to 4a^2-4a-8=0 \to a^2-a-2=0$$
Using quadratic formula for $a^2-a-2=0$, I get solutions $a_1=2 \land a_2=-1$ whose sum is 1.

I checked the numbers too many times, I guess my logic is bad.

Comment: What if $a+2=0$? In which case the parabola becomes a line and then too you will have only one point of intersection.

Comment: BTW, the word is "discriminant".  The determinant is something else.

Comment: @AnuragA Now that I look at the function it really seems obvious. But, how can I get to that solution if I don't see it?

Comment: @HerculePoirot whenever a parabola is described by an equation like $y=px^2+qx+r$, a little note that $p \neq 0$ is always mentioned which people tend to ignore. In your case, the fact that the parameter $a$ is involved in the coefficient of the $x^2$ term should trigger checking what if that coefficient is $0$. You will not get **this** answer from the discriminant approach because when you are using discriminant, you have already assumed that you are working with second degree polynomial.

Comment: @AnuragA Am I not working with a second degree polynomial? How can I determine that? What are the other ways I can solve this problem?

Comment: @HerculePoirot The idea is the polynomial is second degree only if there is a second degree term (i.e. one should have a $x^2$ term). So for this problem you are supposed to look into two cases: **one** where the coefficient of $x^2$ is non-zero (the case you have already done and you got two values for $a$), the **other** when the coefficient of $x^2$ is $0$ (this is the case that I mentioned in my comment))

Comment: @AnuragA So for every second degree polynomial I can have three solutions or is that just the case for this problem since I have the second function to consider?

Answer (score 1):

As per AnuragA's comment, one should consider the possibility of $a+2=0$.